# sqlite3 error on compilation

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am coding on ios7 using Xcode5 and the compiler puts me this error.

> implicit conversion loses integer precision `sqlite3_int64` aka `long long` to `int`.

Below code below:

```
if([self chatId] != nil) {
    [chatId release];
}
chatId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database)];
sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
```

Any help?

Comment: What is means is *Read the message*.

Answer (score 5):

The SQLite3 Row ID is a unique 64-bit signed integer.
Try this:

```
chatId = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithLongLong:sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database)];
```

Answer (score 0):

see implementation of method sqlite3_last_insert_rowid, it returns a long long int value, so you need to
`[NSNumber alloc] initWithLongLong: sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database)];`

```
SQLITE_API sqlite_int64 sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(sqlite3 *db){
  return db->lastRowid;
}
```